# How many reducers can simultaneously run?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Learning Big Data at Uni and I'm kind of confused on the topic of MapReduce. I was wondering how many reducers can run simultaneously. For example lets say if we had 864 reducers, how many could run simultaneously?

Comment: it is calculated as total_resources / resources_per_reducer, e.g. if you have 10 machines x 16GB ram and reducer requires 8GB, you can run 20 reducers

Comment: Your YARN container size and total cluster memory needs to be specified if you want an accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

All of them can run simultaneously depending upon what is the state(health, i.e. no rouge/bad node) of cluster is, what is the capacity of the cluster is and also how free the cluster is. If there are other MR jobs running on the same cluster then out of your 864 reducers only few will go in running state, and once the capacity is free then another set of reducer will start running.

Also there is one case which happens sometimes is when your reducer/mapper keep on preempting each other and takes up the whole memory. Job fails in majority of this case. To avoid this we generally set less number of reducer.

Answer (score 0):

One line answer is - all of them can run simultaneously; as each of the reducer performs an independent unit of task in map reduce framework.

Now, how many would actually run in parallel, or more precisely when each of them would be scheduled to run depends on many factors including but not limited to resource availability, scheduling mechanism, cluster configuration etc.